# Read CSV in pyspark and convert to float

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I'm new to Spark. 
I am trying to read in a CSV file and convert it to a `RowMatrix` using `PySpark`. 
Here is the format of my data:

```
1.,2.,3.,4.,5.

6.,3.,2.,1.,5.

10.,20.,40.,70.,1.

5.,3.,1.,2.,9.
```

My code to read this file as a RDD is as follows:

```
rows = sc.textFile('testmatrix.txt').map( lambda line: line.split(",").map(lambda values: float(values)))
```

I understand from the Spark examples that I will need to create dense Vectors before creating a `RowMatrix`.

My questions is: How can I proceed from the above code to convert the data to dense vectors and ultimately a `RowMatrix`.

Any help is appreciated. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You don't need `denseVectors` you can directly apply `RowMatrix` to a `RDD`:

```py
rows = sc.textFile('testmatrix.txt')\
    .map(lambda line: line.split(","))\
    .map(lambda line: [float(val) for val in line])

from pyspark.mllib.linalg.distributed import RowMatrix
mat = RowMatrix(rows)
```

and back

```py
rowsRDD = mat.rows
```

see https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/mllib-data-types.html#rowmatrix for description

Comment: Thanks for sending me the link to the documentation. It doesn't necessarily answer my question about loading the csv as a matrix. Is the code snippet I posted sufficient to load the csv and convert the matrix elements to floats?

Comment: I've updated my answer with the part on loading and processing your csv. Your solution was correct, but for the last `map` function in which you tried to cast a list to a float.

Comment: Thank you very much. That was exactly what I was missing.

Comment: No problem Linus, don't forget to mark your question as solved :)